# Why is Visual Studio creating .meta files even outside Assets folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, metafile

I have the following project setup:

- Unity project in `C:\XXX`
- Added an another project to solution, located in `C:\XXX\Tests`

Now, whenever adding a class to that Test project, I found that a `.meta` file is being added as well.

This doesn't seem correct as `.meta` files are supposedly only for files inside `Assets`.

Using Process Monitor I discovered that indeed it is devenv.exe that is creating these `.meta` files.

**Quick-fix:**

Using ignores [Visual Studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) and [Unity](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) ignores, these `.meta` files are not committed to the repository,

And adding this to the csproj will hide them:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="**/*.meta" Visible="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But in reality, this only hides the problem ...

And unfortunately, this approach won't work in [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019), forcing one to manually add former code block to each of these 'external' projects.

**Question:**

Why are `.meta` files also created outside `Assets` and how to turn that off?

Comment: Had a similar issue shortly when having multiple projects (assemblies) in Unity. It created `.meta` files even for some of the `.sln` solutions which was really strange. I couldn't reproduce it though, but sometimes it still happens again

Comment: Yes, apparently, it does not always happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, putting this in [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) at root effectively removes the need to manually update each project:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);**\*.meta</DefaultItemExcludes>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But this only hides the problem instead of fixing it...

**Update**

The problem comes from Resharper and has been fixed:

[Avoid creating meta files outside Assets and Packages (#1489)](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/pull/1491)